# Different Images using Accelerometer in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, addition, accelerometer

I am trying to make an app in Xcode 4.3.3 where one image is displayed when the z-axis using the accelerometer is positive. But, when the z-axis becomes negative, I would like a different image to appear. I'm a beginner, so if you could tell me the file in which I should write the code in that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out below links to understand UIAccelerometer

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html

http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C490/html/chapter22.htm

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-accelerometer-in-iphone/

http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-simple-accelerometer-source-code.151394/

You would require to make changes in following function

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
           didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration 
{
    if(acceleration.z<0) {
       imageview.image = //Display image to be displayed when z is negative
    }
    else {
       imageview.image = //Display image to be displayed when z is positive
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I looked through these documents and could not find an answer to my question. Is it even possible to get the different images?